# Objective-C - Get simple HTML source in UITextView - without CSS styles

Tags: android, html, ios, css, objective-c

I want to EDIT an HTML text in a UITextView, this text was created in a web version of the app that allows you to create text with HTML editor (The edit will be with a default font in iOS)

I get the text to be edited in a simple html as below:

```
<p><b>html</b> <u>html</u> <i>html</i></p>
```

But after editing it, I get the html text in UITextView with the code:

```
NSDictionary *exportParams = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:  NSHTMLTextDocumentType};
NSData *htmlData = [_txtDescricao.attributedText dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, _txtDescricao.attributedText.length) documentAttributes:exportParams error:nil];
NSString *descHtml = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:htmlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

HTML text is returned with CSS styles, as shown below:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<title></title>
<meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer">
<style type="text/css">
p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 16.0px 'Helvetica Neue'; color:      #000000; -webkit-text-stroke: #000000}
span.s1 {font-family: 'Helvetica Neue'; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 16.00pt; font-kerning: none}
span.s2 {font-family: 'Helvetica Neue'; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 16.00pt; font-kerning: none}
span.s3 {font-family: 'Helvetica Neue'; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 16.00pt; text-decoration: underline ; font-kerning: none}
span.s4 {font-family: 'Helvetica Neue'; font-weight: normal; font-style: italic; font-size: 16.00pt; font-kerning: none}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1">html</span><span class="s2"> </span><span  class="s3">html</span><span class="s2"> </span><span class="s4">html</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to get the html text in UITextView in simple HTML format (without CSS), as the initial text.

Although it is a valid HTML format, I need the HTML text in the simplified format (without CSS) because I can edit this same text in the Android version of the app, and in Android EditText does not accept HTML text with CSS.

Could anyone help me get the HTML text in UITextView without CSS?

Thanks.

Comment: I've read this question a few times, and don't understand it. So far, I've got: your app presents a UITextView and it allows the user to input simple html.  `myTextView.text` will return whatever the user has entered.  Is that what you want?

Comment: myTextView.text return the text: "html html html", i want get the text like this: <p><b>html</b> <u>html</u> <i>html</i></p>

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, you could manually remove the `style` element of the html string with something like the following:

```
NSString *htmlString = @"Your entire html text as a string";
NSRange firstRange = [htmlString rangeOfString:@"<style type=\"text/css\">"];
NSRange secondRange =  [htmlString rangeOfString:@"</style>"];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(firstRange.location, firstRange.length+secondRange.length);
[htmlString stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];
```

You may have to test this code a bit and get it working for you, but this general should work as a simple solution.

Comment: But I do not want to just remove the styles, i want to remove them, and apply them inside the tags, like: <p><b>html</b> <u>html</u> <i>html</i></p>